# default entry for dropdown in django Form

Tags: django, django-forms

[image]

In a form I have a dropdown list , the default behaviour of django seems to fill the first entry with `----------`.
How can I remove this, so it will just use the firs entry as the default?
(note that the entries may change, so hardcoding a value for `initial=` might not work. )

model:

```
class Job(models.Model):
   ...
   category    = models.ForeignKey(Category, on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with:

Test 1

```
class Job(models.Model):
   ...
   category    = models.ForeignKey(Category,default="Design" on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

As a ForeignKey all related field will have Design as default

Test 2

override the display in Django Admin by create a **form.py** and register it in the **admin.py** file and set the default selected value